Tmux log file seems suspicious
I have switched from a none-Debian distribution to Ubuntu recently, however, I don't come to discover to make my precious Tmux config to work with my current Ubuntu setup, with that there are the a log beside the configuration file. It seems like I have been hacked.
So how to get the tmux.config working ? and if anyone understands this, is this related to hacking?
1721698140.820822 client started (13266): version 3.4, socket /tmp/tmux-1000/default, protocol 8
1721698140.820858 on Linux 6.8.0-38-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun  7 15:25:01 UTC 2024
1721698140.820863 using libevent 2.1.12-stable poll
1721698140.820867 using ncurses 6.4 20240113
1721698140.820886 flags are 0x10010000
1721698140.820902 socket is /tmp/tmux-1000/default
1721698140.820916 trying connect
1721698140.821009 add peer 0x64ebc9e817d0: 6 ((nil))
1721698140.821461 sending message 100 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (4 bytes)
1721698140.821474 sending message 111 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821479 sending message 101 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (14 bytes)
1721698140.821483 sending message 109 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (4 bytes)
1721698140.821486 sending message 102 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821490 sending message 108 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (22 bytes)
1721698140.821494 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (70 bytes)
1721698140.821498 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (5 bytes)
1721698140.821501 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (5 bytes)
1721698140.821504 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (6 bytes)
1721698140.821508 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (6 bytes)
1721698140.821511 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821515 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821518 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821522 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821525 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (18 bytes)
1721698140.821528 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821532 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821535 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (15 bytes)
1721698140.821538 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (21 bytes)
1721698140.821542 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821545 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (7 bytes)
1721698140.821549 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821552 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (7 bytes)
1721698140.821555 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821559 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.821562 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (21 bytes)
1721698140.821565 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821569 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821572 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821576 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821579 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.821582 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.821586 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821589 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821592 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821596 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (7 bytes)
1721698140.821599 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (7 bytes)
1721698140.821603 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.821606 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821609 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (6 bytes)
1721698140.821613 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.821616 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (15 bytes)
1721698140.821620 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821623 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821626 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821630 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (14 bytes)
1721698140.821633 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821636 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.821640 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821644 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821656 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821660 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821664 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821667 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821671 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821674 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821677 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821681 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821684 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821687 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821691 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821694 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821697 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821701 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821704 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821707 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821711 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821714 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821717 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821721 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821724 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821727 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821731 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821734 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821738 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821741 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821744 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821748 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821751 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821754 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821757 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821761 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821764 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821767 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821771 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821774 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821777 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821781 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821784 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821787 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821791 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821794 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821797 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821801 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821804 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821807 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821811 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821814 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821817 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821821 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821824 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821827 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821831 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821834 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821837 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821841 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.821844 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821852 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821855 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821859 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821862 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821865 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821869 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821872 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821875 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821879 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821882 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821885 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821889 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821892 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821895 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821899 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821902 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821905 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821909 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821912 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821916 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821919 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821922 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821926 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821929 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821932 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821935 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821939 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821942 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.821945 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821949 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821952 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821955 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821959 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821962 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.821965 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821969 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821972 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821975 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821979 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821982 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821986 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821989 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.821992 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821996 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.821999 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822002 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822006 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822009 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822012 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822016 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.822019 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.822023 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822026 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822029 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822033 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822036 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822039 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822046 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.822050 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822053 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822056 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822060 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822063 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822067 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822070 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.822073 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822077 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822080 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822083 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822087 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822090 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822094 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.822097 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822101 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822104 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822108 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822111 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822114 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (21 bytes)
1721698140.822118 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822121 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.822125 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (6 bytes)
1721698140.822129 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822133 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.822136 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (15 bytes)
1721698140.822140 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822143 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.822147 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (70 bytes)
1721698140.822151 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (69 bytes)
1721698140.822155 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.822158 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.822162 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.822165 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (15 bytes)
1721698140.822169 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822179 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.822186 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.822190 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (17 bytes)
1721698140.822193 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (10 bytes)
1721698140.822197 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822201 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (9 bytes)
1721698140.822205 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (5 bytes)
1721698140.822208 sending message 112 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (15 bytes)
1721698140.822213 sending message 104 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (0 bytes)
1721698140.822217 sending message 110 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (0 bytes)
1721698140.822221 sending message 107 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (4 bytes)
1721698140.822225 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (16 bytes)
1721698140.822229 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (76 bytes)
1721698140.822233 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (24 bytes)
1721698140.822236 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (19 bytes)
1721698140.822240 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (20 bytes)
1721698140.822244 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (45 bytes)
1721698140.822248 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (23 bytes)
1721698140.822251 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (25 bytes)
1721698140.822255 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (80 bytes)
1721698140.822259 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (44 bytes)
1721698140.822266 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (36 bytes)
1721698140.822271 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (32 bytes)
1721698140.822274 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (41 bytes)
1721698140.822278 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (51 bytes)
1721698140.822282 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (20 bytes)
1721698140.822286 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (23 bytes)
1721698140.822289 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822293 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (28 bytes)
1721698140.822296 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (26 bytes)
1721698140.822300 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (27 bytes)
1721698140.822303 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.822307 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (25 bytes)
1721698140.822311 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (22 bytes)
1721698140.822315 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (54 bytes)
1721698140.822319 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (22 bytes)
1721698140.822322 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (33 bytes)
1721698140.822326 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (14 bytes)
1721698140.822329 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (12 bytes)
1721698140.822333 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (18 bytes)
1721698140.822336 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (17 bytes)
1721698140.822340 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (33 bytes)
1721698140.822344 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (144 bytes)
1721698140.822347 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (26 bytes)
1721698140.822351 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (47 bytes)
1721698140.822354 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (47 bytes)
1721698140.822358 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (16 bytes)
1721698140.822363 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (264 bytes)
1721698140.822367 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (63 bytes)
1721698140.822371 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (24 bytes)
1721698140.822375 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (23 bytes)
1721698140.822379 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (23 bytes)
1721698140.822382 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (19 bytes)
1721698140.822386 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (35 bytes)
1721698140.822389 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.822393 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (13 bytes)
1721698140.822396 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (17 bytes)
1721698140.822399 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (11 bytes)
1721698140.822403 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.822407 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (35 bytes)
1721698140.822410 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (18 bytes)
1721698140.822413 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (31 bytes)
1721698140.822417 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (47 bytes)
1721698140.822420 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (23 bytes)
1721698140.822424 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (16 bytes)
1721698140.822428 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (177 bytes)
1721698140.822431 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (272 bytes)
1721698140.822435 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (39 bytes)
1721698140.822440 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (18 bytes)
1721698140.822443 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (54 bytes)
1721698140.822447 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (35 bytes)
1721698140.822451 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (41 bytes)
1721698140.822454 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (36 bytes)
1721698140.822457 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (68 bytes)
1721698140.822461 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (18 bytes)
1721698140.822464 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (16 bytes)
1721698140.822468 sending message 105 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (16 bytes)
1721698140.822471 sending message 106 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (0 bytes)
1721698140.822543 sending message 200 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (4 bytes)
1721698140.822547 client loop enter
1721698140.823374 peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 message 303
1721698140.823382 open write file 2 -
1721698140.823392 sending message 305 to peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 (8 bytes)
1721698140.823414 write check file 2
1721698140.823526 peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 message 304
1721698140.823530 write 58 to file 2
1721698140.823535 peer 0x64ebc9e817d0 message 203
1721698140.823539 file 2 58 bytes left
1721698140.823554 write check file 2
1721698140.823558 client loop exit


Why do you think any of that is hacking?

I am not by any mean good at reading logs, and also I have not used tmux that often, but in the way that my config is not working and the everything that has `sending message to peer XXXXXXXXX' that was my consern?

If you want anyone (including me) to evaluate your tmux configuration, you should at least include your config file, its location and the command you use to start tmux in your question. Also, please include the terminal (not log) output when you have started tmux, and the output of tmux ls.

The sending message xxx to peer is a normal log message in tmux, as is evident by this related Q&A.
This is because tmux uses a server/client structure, so it is only logical that the server sends messages to the clients.
Jumping to unfounded conclusions about "being hacked" is neither constructive, nor a good idea in general.
